# Excel - Using a cell reference as a TableName in a fully qualified structured reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I am putting together a dashboard to quickly see counts of orders from vendors
[image of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFz9N.png)

The simplified version of the formula I am using is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(
        SUMPRODUCT(
              (TEXT(Table1[[openDate]:[openDate]],"YYYY")=$B$2)
               *
              (TEXT(Table1[[openDate]:[openDate]],"MMMM")=C$3)
              /
              COUNTIF(Table1[[orderNum]:[orderNum]],Table1[[orderNum]:[orderNum]]&"")
               )
        ,"")
```

Each table is a separate worksheet for each vendor. What I am trying to accomplish is have the table reference (Table1 in this example) be able to be a cell reference. This would allow the formula to be pre-populated in the dashboard and not require manually updating the table name each time a new table is created.

I have created a VBA module that pulls all table names and places them into a table on a reference worksheet [image of reference table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJNwU.png):

```
  Sub GetTableNameList()
    
        Dim x As ListObject
    
        Dim y As Worksheet
      
        Dim z As Long
        
            z = -1
           
            For Each y In Worksheets
            
            For Each x In y.ListObjects
            
                z = z + 1
        Sheets("Reference").Range("B3").Offset(z).Value = x.Name
        
        Next x
        
        Next
         
    End Sub
```

My thought is that as new tables are created the cell in the formula would reference the next line  on the reference table. I am open to all other suggestions for how to complete this task. My only stipulation is there needs to be little to no interaction required by the end user for this to work properly.

NOTE: Dashboard begins blank, and there are no tables to reference. Tables/worksheets are added by the user as they select vendors they wish to track.

---

Update:

I am attempting to use my reference table by adding

```
TEXT(EvaluateString("Reference!$B6"&"[[openDate]:[openDate]])"),"YYYY")=$B$2)
```

Where "EvaluateString" is:

```
   Function EvaluateString(strTextString As String)
    
        Application.Volatile
    
        EvaluateString = Evaluate(strTextString)

    End Function
```

I feel like I am close,  and it may just be a syntax error at this point. I need to find a way for the string to be recognized as a structured reference.

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2016 is what I have currently. If this is a factor, I can request 2019 or 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `INDIRECT`. E.g. With `"Table1"` entered into `A1`, `TEXT(INDIRECT(A1&"[[openDate]:[openDate]]"),"YYYY")` will be understood as `TEXT(Table1[[openDate]:[openDate]],"YYYY")`

Keep in mind, however, that too many `INDIRECT` formulas slows down Excel considerably. Since you're also using VBA, you could also consider something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    
        TableString = Target.Value
    
        Built_Formula = "=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(" & TableString & "[[openDate]:[openDate]],""YYYY"")=$F$2)*(TEXT(" & TableString & "[[openDate]:[openDate]],""MMMM"")=F$3)/" _
    + "COUNTIF(" & TableString & "[[orderNum]:[orderNum]]," & TableString & "[[orderNum]:[orderNum]]&"""")),"""")"

        Range("A2").Formula = Built_Formula

    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

This would rebuild the formula each time you change the value in A1 (e.g. make it a dropdown of those table names).

Or even do the calc in VBA! :)

Comment: I like this approach. However I am admittedly very green in VBA. In an earlier attempt I tried pulling the table name using this function `Function TableName(cell As Range) As String
   
    Dim Name As String
    Name = vbNullString
    On Error Resume Next
    Name = cell.ListObject.Name
    TableName = Name
    
End Function`   Perhaps a combination of the two could be used to create a custom function? Thoughts?

Comment: Suppose you could if you know that each Sheet(vendor) will always have some cell (e.g. A1) inside the required Table. If so, you could do `Sheets(vendor).Range("A1").ListObject.Name` to get the name, use it in the formula, `Evaluate` it, and return the answer, based solely on the vendor name, assuming you already have that in the dashboard somewhere. Might be a bit of a challenge. If you want to give it a go, check out how to use "Evaluate" online. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your assistance here. I was unable to figure out this issue using VBA entirely (  likely a issue with my experience level and not the capability of the program ). Using INDIRECT in conjunction with a macro to sort the worksheets as well as pull the table names has given me the desired results. I can work on increasing the efficiency at a later date....Thank you again :)